# Combo box for names isn't returning the correct value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a combo box for a persons last name and first name. The combo box works fine you can see a complete list of all the people, however a problem arises when I select someone who shares a surname with someone else.

For example:

```
Surname | First Name
Romas      Issac
Romas      Tony
```

If I select Romas Tony in the combo box I get the value for Romas Issac for the first name. This is a real problem as I'm trying to launch a query based on what is selected - how can I ensure that the correct first name is selected?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "...I get the value for Romas Issac..."? How do you get the value? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the primary key from the table where that data originates to your combobox as a third, hidden column (to make the column hidden, you can just set the column width to 0; actually, I usually add this as the FIRST column, because then you can leave the entries in the 'Column Widths' property empty for all the other columns). Set its 'Bound Column' property to the number of the primary key column. It is generally good practice to do this with ALL comboboxes that get their data from tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you haved stored the names in two seperate collumns, you have to make sure you are getting both .collumn(0) & .collumn(1), but wakjah's answer is always a good idea ;)